# Temperature on MAC and keyboard cover

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook, cpu-temperature

I use the MacBook Pro and since it cost me expensive, I decided to add some security methods for it.

I bought a special MacBook keyboard cover (on the left on the link [here](https://www.bestadvisor.com/macbook-keyboard-covers)) in the hope that it will start to get less dust and the keyboard will not get so dirty.

But after about two months I noticed that my MAC is starting to get warmer. Tell me please, it can be as it is connected with a rug? Maybe it closed all the "holes" and the air does not condense?

Comment: Yes, it surely can impact. Can you just use it a few days without the cover and see whether it changes?

Answer (score 0):

Overheat can be based in a lot of other factors. Because it's a MacBook, doesn't mean that it will not overheat.

There are many factors that may have caused this problem:

1) **You have installed many programs.** Yes. Macbooks, due to their very lightweight Operating System, they don't have much RAM. Many installed apps, can impact very much on their performance.

2) **You have 1+ antivirus or a very "heavy" antivirus.**  Many A/V'es are considered "heavy" for a number of reasons. For example; AVG is a very lightweight A/V. (And a very good one...)     Mcafee is very "heavy". It makes a lot of scans and generally, its recommended only in systems with a "+" RAM and CPU performance. But its considered very good also.   [Here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/which-free-antivirus-is-the-lightest-on-system-memory-usage/) is a link to a test, that was done into several A/V'es and shows very detailed what i have said here.
Also, MacBooks and MacOS is a very secure system, that some users dont even use an A/V.   ***To conclude***, you should leave only 1 A/V, or if you have only 1, try to replace it with something else.

3) **For what you're using it.**   If you are using it for 4K Video Editing, with Premiere, then if it overheats and doesn't burn you*, you have to be happy. I'm not saying that Macbooks cant handle 4K Editing in Premiere, but its very stressful. 
**

.
.
.

**FOOTNOTES:**

- *Also, can you specify the Macbook model and specifications, so that my answer is more related?*

**   *Can you write what use you are doing to it? Like, coding, only watching videos, edit, gaming, etc.*

- *Can you uncover the keyboard from your cover and update this thread? That could be a reason for overheat. (Apple always find ways and that area may be an air condenser.*

Comment: Well... I think I understand because of what the problem is. I need to check, thanks

Comment: @NicholasButler Ok. I’m waiting for an update!